# Canvas cylinder color was not fill 100% seeing some gap in the top of the cylinder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on canvas cylinder and I am created cylinder fill with percentage value when you 100% color has to fill 100% but I am seeing some minute gap in the top.I have tried adding some properties in my custom function drawCylinderprogress().

I have created one center line (threshold) that has to be in curve line but right now i can see as straight line i have the following code for that.

Here is the code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');  
function myCurve(x,y, w, h, vRadius){ 
    context.translate(x,y);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0,0);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(90,20,150,0);
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.strokeStyle = 'Orange';
    context.stroke();
    context.strokeStyle = '#000';
}
myCurve()
```

Here is the code

```
function drawCylinderprogress(x, y, w, h, vRadius, fillStyle, strokeStyle) {
    var w2 = w / 2;
    var h2 = h / 2;
    var ytop = -h2;
    var cpYtop = -h2 - vRadius;
    var ybottom = h2;
    var cpYbottom = h2 + vRadius;
    ctx.save();     
    ctx.translate(x, y);    
    ctx.beginPath();    
    ctx.moveTo(-w2, ytop);  
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(-w2, cpYtop/360, w2, cpYtop/360 , w2 , ytop); 
    ctx.lineTo(w2, ybottom);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(w2, cpYbottom, -w2, cpYbottom, -w2, ybottom);
    ctx.closePath();    
    performDraw(fillStyle); 
    ctx.restore();  
}
```

I added one more condition check

```
    if (h2 == 100)      
{
    //alert("checking");
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(-w2, cpYtop/3, w2, cpYtop/3, w2 , ytop);

}
else(h2 <= 100)
{
    //alert("checking 2");
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(-w2, cpYtop/360, w2, cpYtop/360, w2 , ytop);
}
```

If my h2 was ==100 else but I am getting. But still I am not getting

I have modified ctx.bezierCurveTo(-w2, cpYtop/360, w2, cpYtop/360 , w2 , ytop); this line to `ctx.bezierCurveTo(-w2, cpYtop/3, w2, cpYtop/3 , w2 , ytop);`

If I gave 20% the fill it was not looking like curve it was looking like straight line

But if I gave 100% it was filling to the top.

I am not understanding why it was not happening.
Kindly help me for the above query

Here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/E6PJC/).

Comment: try this: ctx.bezierCurveTo(-w2, cpYtop/3, w2, cpYtop/3, w2 , ytop);

Comment: @h3li0s thank you so much can you please help me on middle curve it is not looking like curve when it is 58% / ??????